# Multiprocessing of python scripts

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, xargs

I would like to run multiple python scripts (lets say script1.py to script10.py) in parallel in a bash shell. Can someone advise what is the best way to run all simultaneously using xargs command? or is there any other suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why exactly do you want to run it in a bash shell? If there's no specific reason, I'd suggest you to use multiprocessing package to spawn a process for each script and execute them in parallel.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53912275/2836621

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash:

```
for i in {1..10}; do 
    python script${i}.py &
done
```

Comment: and use `wait` bash command if you want to wait for the tasks finish.

Comment: Thanks @rene-d. Once I run a single code as (python script1.py) in a bash command it works but when I save the loop in a bash file and then run, it says:  python: command not found. Any idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: What is your environnement, Linux/macOS ? Windows ? Basically in Linux or macOS I can't see no difference between running from prompt or running from a script file the python command (unless python is a bash alias).

Comment: I'm using Windows10, however I installed bash and defined python path in my bashrc. But that doesn't work when I execute bash script

Comment: and if you type bash, got the bash prompt and type python : what happens? (probably command not found) Personnaly I gave up using python on my w10 computer :p

Answer (score 0):

There are some considerations you need to take into account.  (that other answers haven't taken into account)

- Are the scripts developed to run independently?  If that is the case this is easier.  If not then you will need a pipeline of scripts to manage the dependencies like Python's Luigi.
- The scripts may require different python interpreter versions. (2.7 vs 3.7 etc..)
- If you do decide to continue in Bash then the usage of nohup would make sure the process doesn't quit when the calling process is ended.

This isn't as easy of a question as you think it might be.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. All scripts are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `xargs -P<number>` for this kind of use cases, specially because it'll wait for all running children to finish.

Say you have several scripts and but still e.g. at most 4 in parallel, you could:

```
ls -1 ./script*.py | xargs -I% -P4 sh -c '%'
```

If you happen to need passing more arguments to your scripts, just add them after above `%` (inside the quotes)

Comment: Thanks @jjo. Once I run the line it gives me the ImportError message. Seems like that xargs can't find specific python path. Is there any way to address python path? I already defined it in my bashrc.